# Locale interpretation and code generation in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to use the export command to generate code based on a simulation of a state machine defined within a locale, where transitions between states occur based on certain events.

```
theory SimpleStateMachine
  imports Main
begin

locale StateMachine =
  fixes
    states :: "'state set"
    and evs  :: "'ev set"
    and initial :: "'state ⇒ bool"
    and stateTrans :: "'inE ⇒ ('state ⇒ 'state ⇒ bool)"
begin
  inductive reachable:: "'state ⇒ bool" where 
    base: "initial x ⟹ reachable x" |
    step: "(∃ y i. (reachable y ∧
                    stateTrans i x y)) ⟹ reachable x"
```

To do this, I need to use the interpretation command to define an arbitrary state machine based on said locale.

```
global_interpretation interp_1: StateMachine "states" "events"  "(λ x . True)"  "(λ i x y . True)"
  defines reachable_def = interp_1.reachable

export_code
  reachable_def 
in Haskell module_name simple_haskell_3
```

What I would like to know is how to:

1. Define a set of arbitrary states (e.g. "a, b, c") and events (e.g. "i1, i2") in my interpretation.
2. Define the interpretation of the "initial" and "stateTrans" functions of the locale so that only some of the states (e.g. only "a") have the value of the initial predicate be True and that the proper transitions between states are defined (e.g. stateTrans has the True value  for the parameters "i1 a b", indicating that event i1 causes a transition from state a to state b).
3. Specify the necessary proof in my interpretation so that export can have the required code equations for "reachable_def".

Comment: I must misunderstand the question, but 1. with two datatypes, one for states `datatype state = a | b | c` and one for events. Then 2. with fun, like a normal function. 3 is more complicated, see the code generation tutorial for inductive predicates.